# Restrict user account to 'only' remote Powershell sessions

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Is it possible to only delegate a enough permissions for a user to only be able to utilize a Remote Powershell session?

I have a limited set of scripts that I want to run from a central location against a set of servers using a designated service account.

What I don't want is for this service user to be able to do things like login to a computer.

Is this possible? Does removing the right to login also remove the right to execute a Remote Powershell session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Powershell Remoting/WinRM session is a network logon.  So if you want to prevent that user from logging in to a computer **interactively,** deny him or her the ability to log on to the console and deny the ability to log on through Remote Desktop.  Do this through either the local security policy, or through Group Policy if the computer is in a domain.  This means the user account will still be able to establish a Powershell Remoting session, but will not be able to log on to the same computer interactively.

Comment: Exactly the confirmation I was after.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to denying interactive logons, you might want to restrict the remote users access to a [remote endpoint](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/31/introduction-to-powershell-endpoints.aspx) that exposes a [constrained runspace](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/04/02/build-constrained-powershell-endpoint-using-configuration-file.aspx).

Essentially, you configure an endpoint on the remote system that when connected to, removes all cmdlets from the session and exports *only* the cmdlets you've white-listed. This also allows you to expose proxy functions with additional input validation and logging, rather than giving the remote user "full control".

It requires some work to set up, but in the end decreases the chance that the remote user breaks something by accident.

It's the same approach used by the PowerShell v5 "JEA" module (Just-Enough-Admin), but you can implement constrained runspaces starting from version 3.0